# Is there a way in VSTS to disable code edit directly to all branch

Tags: azure-devops

I created a new project and some branch, I now want to disable edit code directly in branch,  is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can restrict edit of branches with pull requests and branch policies: [Improve code quality with branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops)

Comment: thank you , but how i can prevent other to do not change my settings

Comment: @KivenWanda you can edit security settings of git repos [Default Git repository and branch permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/default-git-permissions?view=azure-devops). Deny the "Edit policies, Manage permissions, Remove others' locks" right for other users